# JSXElement have different API form the doc

Tags: javascript, babeljs

The docs says that JSXElement have this API:

> t.jSXElement(openingElement, closingElement, children, selfClosing)

When, instead, I got this:

```
JSXElement(elementItself, fileInfo)
```

Did I miss something or the docs ain't right?

Comment: Are you have in mind specification that is in draft - https://github.com/facebook/jsx ?

Comment: I meant this: https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-types

Comment: What is `JSXElement(elementItself, fileInfo)`? Where do you see that?